# How to (is it even practical to want to) use HATEOAS where you need to provide links to application state?

Tags: rest, hateoas

I have been happily trying HATEOAS for the first time, with a Web App that suits really well because the user navigates through a tree of "nodes".

Each time the user clicks on a link to a node, the server returns the data for that node and the *server* URL for the data for the related notes.

HATEOAS response body:

```
    {"description":"A good node!",
     "category":"IDEAL",
     "placement":"Q16","
     "_links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost:8081/position?id=393"}},
     "_embedded":{
       "parent":
       {"placement":"root","category":"IDEAL","_links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost:8081/position?id=384"}}},
      "next_nodes":[
           {"placement":"Q13","category":"GOOD","_links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost:8081/position?id=362"}}}
           {"placement":"J10","category":"BAD","_links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost:8081/position?id=365"}}}
       ]}}
```

When the single page web app client displays the data for the node and its relationship to the other nodes, the user clicks to indicate traversal to a new node, and the web app client fetches the data from the HATEOAS supplied next server URL.

This delivers the promise of HATEOAS - the state is in the response body, as are the server URLs for the next state, so the web app client never needs to know anything other than the first root URL.

However this falls to pieces (apparently) when (obviously) the user says "I want a URL (a client URL) for this node, so I can return to it".

For the web app client using HATEOAS, the only representation available of the "current node" is the "_self" link.  Which is effectively opaque.

So how do you embed that in a web-client route/link for the user to save and return to?

In my application pictured above I find myself forced to also share the position id with the web client, which is then forced to reconstruct the server URL for *that position*.

Is this an expected effect of HATEOAS?   It seems at face value to almost completely break it, but surely there is something basic I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this in the past by using urls such as:

```
https://webapplication.example.org/#http://api.example.org/some/resource
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.   I can see that it is an option, and indeed a valid answer to "how to do it", but I dislike the way that it exposes the fact that the server API is there and where it is.   Then you start thinking "OK, do I obfuscate/encode" ... then you start thinking "really?  All this extra HATEOAS bloat in my server, and now encoding URLs in my client ... for what?   This is the "do I even want to do this" part of my question.  I'm looking at my server realising how much easier to read it would be without the HATEOAS - and that even with Spring helping, and feeling the pull...

Comment: I don't think I can really tell you 'if you want this'. It's not a clear enough question with an objective answer. I've been very successful and happy with my HAL service, and you're always going to leak something to the client. The idea of a generic client that could potentially also point to different implementations of the same HAL-based service (to me) is appealing.

Comment: Yeah "do I want this" is a wrong paraphrase I did of myself.   "Is it practical and beneficial" is more the right question.   Thanks for sharing how it works for you in practice.   I'm still not comfortable with `https://app.route/#server.route`  ... I guess I need to mull on that

Comment: @GreenAsJade I understand the hesitation, but yea it's a bit hard to come up with a value statement without really quantifying 'what are the drawbacks of having the server endpoint in a uri' vs 'what are the benefits you get from hateaos'. If it's solely aesthetics you hypothetically could create a sort of 'url shortcode service' that maps short opaque identifiers to full server uris. This service could itself be HAL and use a templated link

Comment: This is perhaps the whole reason for my question: it "seems" wrong, but I can't put a finger on why, other than the server API is exposed.   So I asked what the experience is out there.  Since asking, I found another differently worded question that has the same answer you gave.   So I guess this is what people do.   FWIW, this ended my experiment with HATEOAS :)   Since my sever API is only consumed by my own client, there is no benefit to "discoverability" and a range of costs to it - I now know what those are :)  Thanks!